# Get ping.exe -t condition and log if no reply

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to log ping results if the response doesnt have a reply

My final line is essentially this and I'm wondering how I can capture and log lines that do not get a valid response.

Ping.exe -t 8.8.8.8 | ForEach{"{0}-{1}"-f(Get-Date),$_} > "C:\Users\test.txt"

Any pointers as to how about I could filter those responses?

Comment: [1] use `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection` instead of `Ping.exe`. [2],save it to a $Var. [3] build a `PSCustomObject` from that info. [4] include the `online/offline` status in the PSCO. [5] send the info to a CSV or to a plain text file as preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Show-Menu{
param([string]$Title = 'Server Selection')
Clear-Host
Write-Host "$Title"
Write-Host "1) Remote Server 1"
Write-Host "2) Remote Server 2"}
function Show-Menu1{
param([string]$Title = 'Server Selection')
Clear-Host
Write-Host "$Title"
Write-Host "1) Local Connection 1"
Write-Host "2) Local Connection 2"}
$user = $env:USERNAME
Show-Menu1 -Title 'Local Server Selection'
$Selection1 = Read-Host "Please Make a Selection"
switch($Selection1){
1{$LocalServer = "Server1"} 
2{$LocalServer = "Server2"}}
Show-Menu1 -Title 'Remote Server Selection'
$Selection = Read-Host "Please Make a Selection"
switch($Selection){
1{$RemoteServer = "8.8.8.8"} #Google DNS
2{$RemoteServer = "8.8.4.4"}}
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('MM_dd_yy')
$basedir = "C:\Users\$user\Logs\$LocalServer\$RemoteServer\$today"+".txt"
Write-Host "Running Remote Test on $RemoteServer From $LocalServer Press <CTRL> + <C> to Stop"
$shouldExecute = $true
while ($shouldExecute -eq $true){
$Result = Test-NetConnection $RemoteServer -InformationLevel "Detailed"
if($Result.PingSucceeded - $false){
"$(Get-Date) | Remote: $($Result.ComputerName) | Ping Succeeded: $($Result.PingSucceeded) | From: $($LocalServer) | By: $($user)" | Out-File -Append $basedir -Verbose}
$today = (Get-Date).ToString('MM_dd_yy')
$basedir = "C:\Users\$user\Logs\$LocalServer\$RemoteServer\$today"+".txt"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```bsh
param(
    $ip = '8.8.8.9',
    $shouldExecute = $true,
    $logFile = "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"
)

while ($shouldExecute -eq $true) {
    $result = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $ip -InformationLevel "Detailed"    
    if ($result.PingSucceeded -eq $false) {        
        "$(Get-Date) | IP: $($result.ComputerName) | Ping Succeeded: $($result.PingSucceeded)" `
            | Out-File -Append $logFile -Verbose
    }
}
```